# "Maximum execution time exceeded" when processing my queue

Tags: php, mysql, queue

I have made a queue using MySQL and PHP. The PHP script first retrieves all the tasks to be done from database and then executes all the tasks one by one using loop. But since there are many tasks and each task require a lot of time, the result is an error of 'Maximum execution time exceeded'.

How can I fix this? Please don't suggest I edit php.ini. I tested this on my browser but the PHP script will be invoked using cron.

Comment: I would suggest that you type the _exact_ title of your question in Google; I believe it will be immediately obvious which link answers your question.

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea to reply to the person who helps you - even if only to thank them! `:)`

Comment: Why is my question downvoted like this? Did i ask something wrong? Now i have been banned from asking any more questions.

Comment: Ashutosh - question bans are temporary, I think, and should indicate why they were applied. You can always contact a mod, or maybe ask on Meta, if you need more info. I'd imagine your question ban has now gone, anyway? (Aside: I didn't see an alert for your above note - you need to ping users with @halfer if you want them to see your message. However since this is your question, comments under it will be notified to you automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set this piece of code on the top of your php code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Or create in the same folder a .htaccess file with this code in it:

```
php_value max_execution_time 0
```